# Using Rowlock when inserting data helps..?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, blocking, query-hints

I want to use ROWLOCK option in sql server when inserting data into table. Does it helps in any manner. Will it help me to decrease blocking in my database?

Answer (score 2):

Using ROWLOCK is a hint to the SQL Server query optimizer that you know better than it does about this SQL query. It basically says lock the table/view rows affected by the FROM clause of your query rather than escalating to a page or table lock.

If applied by an experienced developer or administrator, it *might* help with blocking in very specific circumstances. But in general I would leave the locking strategy up to the query optimizer unless you've clearly identified that locking isn't being done efficiently for a specific query.

There is a [good article on lock escalation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverstorageengine/archive/2006/05/17/lock-escalation.aspx) for SQL Server 2005, though I believe there have been some changes in SQL Server 2008. There is a [decent article on locking in SQL Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190615%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).